# How do I select all options in a jQuery Chosen multi-select AFTER search filtering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

Title pretty much says it all.

I have several select boxes on a page, all dynamically generated in an ASP.NET webform, some with hundreds of options.  I'd like to be able to type in a search string and then select all entries that match.

It's easy to select all and deselect all using javascript on the base select control and then calling `$('#control-id').trigger('chosen:update');` but I am having issues when trying to only select the options matching the search filter.

I'm not picky as to how this is done, either with a "Select all" option, an extra button, or a keystroke.  This is for a backend dev-only page, so the UI doesn't have to be 100% intuitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up solving this by altering the chosen plugin and adding the following code to `AbstractChosen.prototype.keyup_checker`:

```
case 65:
  if (evt.ctrlKey && this.results_showing) {
    if (typeof onSelectAll == 'function') {
       onSelectAll($(this.container).attr('id'), $(this.form_field).attr('id'));
        this.results_hide();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Basically, if Ctrl-A is pressed while the Chosen select is open, it will call a user-defined delegate `onSelectAll` with the Chosen container's id and the underlying select's id as arguments.  If the Ctrl key is not pressed, I want this to fall through to the default, which allows search string entry to work as usual.

Back on my page I have the following:

```
function onSelectAll(containerId, selectId) {
  var ids = [];
  $("#" + containerId).find('.active-result').each(function () { ids.push(parseInt($(this).attr('data-option-array-index'))); });
  $(ids).each(function () { $($('#' + selectId + ' option')[this]).attr('selected', 'selected'); });
  $('#' + selectId).trigger('chosen:updated');
}
```

This gets the array indexes of the visible results in the Chosen container, marks them as selected in the underlying select control, and then causes the Chosen container to update.

I am aware it's not entirely kosher to change the meaning of a standard keyboard shortcut, but in an informal poll of the three other devs most likely to actually use this thing, they all suggested it, so I think I'm in the clear for now.  That said, suggestions to improve and clean up my javascript are quite welcome - I've been doing backend and SQL stuff for so long I've totally lost my UI chops.