# How to select all items in jquery chosen

Tags: jquery, multi-select

How to select all items in jquery chosen i know

```
$('.my-select-all').click(function(){
    $('#my_select option').prop('selected', true); // Selects all options
});
```

But i need select only search results. Thanks.

Comment: Where is your search result ?

Comment: in chosen . When chosen select dropdown i can type a keyword and plugin filter items by this word. (sorry for bad english)

Comment: Can you create a demo?

Comment: https://sargas.pro/chosen/ look at Multiple Select and try type for example "a" in select and plugin filter items and you see items that contains a

Comment: So you want all the selected options in the multiselect?

Comment: While searching you will get a list of options. You want to select all the searched options. Is it what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: Yes. I need work with searched options . I what select them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find 2 answers 
1. http://robido.com/jquery/add-selectdeselect-optgroup-click-events-harvests-chosen-jquery-plugin/

2. [How do I select all options in a jQuery Chosen multi-select AFTER search filtering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23157212/how-do-i-select-all-options-in-a-jquery-chosen-multi-select-after-search-filteri)